# XPath Evaluation fails while using with AutoPilot in VTD-XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, vtd-xml

I have a bunch of xml's which contains elements's with namespaces and i am using VTD-XML to parse that xml. But when i tries to use an xpath to get a namespaced element. It will not fetch at all?
Here is the xml sample

```
<startQuery logLinkID="797ca6afb7a32458:1619f4f5:14d8fa72127:-7ff5" modelName="SampleModel" tracerString="tracer:: std.Page1.Pane1">
   <xql:XQL xmlns:xql="someNameSpace" cellCountThreshold="1000000" dumpOptions="" enableThresholdDrillDown="false" maxOverridenValueArraySize="" returnFullPath="true" returnNormalizedXql="true">
      <HiddenValues errors="true" nulls="false" zeros="false" />
      <CellAttributes cellsAsAttachment="true" editUEVInfo="false" formattingInfo="false" uevInfo="false" writeBackInfo="true" /></xql:XQL>
</startQuery>
```

But when i use the xpath as

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(nav);
ap.selectXPath("//HiddenValues");
```

it works correctly but, when i use this xpath

```
ap.selectXPath("//XQL");
```

it will not work.

Please help me how i can ignore namespaces while evaluating XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know VTD-XML, but it looks like you need to declare the namespace of the element `XQL`.  So after a quick loko at http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/ximpleware/AutoPilot.html, I would say:

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(nav);
ap.declareXPathNameSpace("xql", "someNameSpace");
ap.selectXPath("//xql:XQL");
```

Or if you want to avoid the descendant axis:

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(nav);
ap.declareXPathNameSpace("xql", "someNameSpace");
ap.selectXPath("/startQuery/xql:XQL");
```

Bonus tip: **if** `startQuery` **was** in another namespace, just declare several prefixes (they do not have to match with the prefixes in the input, the URI they are bound to have to match):

```
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(nav);
ap.declareXPathNameSpace("h", "urn:hypotheticalNamespace");
ap.declareXPathNameSpace("xql", "someNameSpace");
ap.selectXPath("/h:startQuery/xql:XQL");
```

Note: not tested.

Comment: That works like charm. Thanks for the solution. The bonus tip you mentioned doesnot work here since startQuery is in same namespace. But, thanks for the tip.

Comment: That's why "if ... was" is in bold: I am not saying it applies here, I just explain the general idea :-)

Comment: yeah i understood what you are saying. i will try to remember it in the future. Thanks a lot

Comment: Go to vtd website and download the vtdnav.java, then compile the lib. This problem should go away. It will ignore the XPath without namespace declaration.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author i am having the latest vtd-xml 2.11.jar only. This is the last version they have released. So how can i get latest vtdNav.java file and please tell me the steps.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360885/how-to-ingore-namespace-prefixes-on-vtd-xpath-lookup